# How to convert a time (01:10:00) to 1h 10m short code in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, php-carbon

I have to convert a time `01:10:00` to `1h 10m` and also i have to exclude if the hours Or minutes is zero.

Ex:

`01:10:00` --> `1h 10m`

`01:00:00` ---> `1h`

`00:10:00` ---> `10m`

I have tried like this:

`date('g', strtotime('01:10:00')).'h'.' '.date('i', strtotime('01:10:00')).'m'`

But is there any other simple way to achieve this. using `Carbon::parse()->Something()` something like that

Kindly help me how to achieve this

Comment: Why are you tagging both momentjs and php, which is it? What have you tried to do this, please share your code!

Comment: Hi mate, I have removed the momentjs tagging. I expect, is there any other way to achieve this via JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can use a mix of Carbon's `createFromTimeString` and `diffForHumans`.

```php
use Carbon\CarbonInterface;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;

$result = Carbon::createFromTimeString('01:10:00')
    ->diffForHumans(Carbon::today(), CarbonInterface::DIFF_ABSOLUTE, true, 3);
```

Comment: Its works except and i have added like this

```\Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimeString('00:10:00')->diffForHumans(Carbon::now()->startOfDay(), CarbonInterface::DIFF_ABSOLUTE, true, 3)```

Comment: That works too. `Illuminate\Support\Carbon` just extends from `Carbon\Carbon`.

Comment: `01:10:00` here is a duration, not a date, so it's semantically more relevant to use `CarbonInterval` and avoid to create 2 more dates objects and make useless diff calculation (see my answer)

Comment: Haven't dabbled with the interval class yet. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

```php
use Carbon\CarbonInterface;
use Carbon\CarbonInterval;

echo CarbonInterval::createFromFormat('H:i:s', '01:10:00')
    ->forHumans(CarbonInterface::DIFF_ABSOLUTE, true, 3);
```